# Batch - How to replace exclamation mark with expression in if with delayed expension?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, scripting, windows-scripting

In order to [*return* parameter values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50670442/5233188) i need to change a string which requires to replace exclamation marks with an expression so that these exclamation marks are escaped later in the process. The current solution doesn't work inside an if. The following working script shows the issue quite well:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

    SET string="World^! wasserschutzpolizei^!"

    REM REM Works quite well here!
    REM SET "return1=!string:"=""!"
    REM SET "return1=%return1:!=^^^!%"
    REM SET "return1=!return1:""="!"
    REM ECHO !return1!

    IF NOT "!string!"=="" (
        SET "return1=!string:"=""!"

        REM This line doesn't work because of the % % inside the if...
        REM Because it is one logical line.
        SET "return1=%return1:!=^^^!%"
        SET "return1=!return1:""="!"

        ECHO !return1!
    )

    EXIT /B 0
ENDLOCAL
```

I had one non-working approach which uses `CALL SET`:

`CALL SET "return1=%%return1:!=^^^!%%"` but this doesn't work.

For an answer consider that I need delayed expension for other stuff too.

So, how do I need to change the code, espacially line `SET "return1=%return1:!=^^^!%"` so that it works inside the if?

Comment: What exactly do you expect this script to do? Can you show an example output?

Comment: @jwdonahue
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50671151/5233188) answer of [my](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50670442/5233188) question, but the manipulation of the string and the `FOR ...` part is in an `IF`. An example is even provided in this question, just incomment the commented block...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using multi-line statements in batch scripts. It's not just difficult to get them right, they are hard to debug while developing the code. Delayed expansion is most useful when you need to use variables within variable replacement expressions.  Here's your code the simple way:

```
@setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
@set prompt=$G

set input="World^! wasserschutzpolizei^!"

@rem Works quite well here!
@set "return1=!input:"=""!"
@set "return1=%return1:!=^^^!%"
@set "return1=!return1:""="!"
@echo %return1%

@if not "!input!"=="" call :DoIt
@echo %return1%
@exit /b 0

:DoIt
@set "return1=!input:"=""!"
@set "return1=%return1:!=^^^!%"
@set "return1=!return1:""="!"
@exit
```

Use subroutines when a short simple expression can't be used for if/loop bodies.

Comment: I know that I can use subroutines but I rather like to use every trick the language has...

Answer (score 0):

If you reversed your thinking and instead of using `IF NOT …(`, used `IF …`, you wouldn't have that problem as you wouldn't be setting variables within a block:

```bat
@ECHO OFF
SET "string=World! wasserschutzpolizei!"

IF "%string%"=="" EXIT /B 1

SET "return1=%string:"=""%"
SET "return1=%return1:!=^^^!%"
SET "return1=%return1:""="%"
ECHO %return1%

PAUSE
EXIT /B 0
```

The string will now have pre-escaped exclamation marks ready for your later process.

Answer (score 0):

Like the answer of Compo, but this one works also for more than one return variable.

```
IF defined string (
  SET "return1=!string:"=""!"
)
IF defined string (
    SET "return1=%return1:!=^^^!%"
    SET "return1=!return1:""="!"
)
```

It splits the code into two seperate blocks, therefore the percent expansion will work

Comment: Is there no other way to use some tricky kind of double delayed expansion so that all stays in one if (...) ?